# Copy file using MSI file

Tags: windows-installer

I have a very simple task to complete and need some help. I've been asked for an msi file containing 1 configuration file to be copied to the target machine. This msi file will be deployed to user's machines using SCCM. The file should be copied to the same directory on each machine.
Can I package up just a batch file for this or do I need and exe? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of configuration file is this? There are several problems with MSI and the deployment of configuration files. Will the file be written to, or is it static?

Comment: It is a static XML config file

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this without the use of a bat file or executable.
I created a VS2008 Setup Project, created the folder structure on the Target Machine File System and dropped the file in. I built this and tested it on one of the devices and the file was updated successfully. Very simple now I know how to do it!